# Is it possible to mirror a method?

Tags: c#, reflection

for example, there are bunch of overloads of method:

```
public void MyLongFunctionName(string arg1,...) ...
public void MyLongFunctionName(int arg1,...) ...
//.... many different argument types
```

To make a shortcut of that long function, i used  i.e. `my()` :

```
public void my(string arg1,...) ...
public void my(int arg1,...) ...
....
```

however,  is something like this possible to make `my()` as a shortcut of `MyLongFunctionName()` , without defining bunch of `my()` methods (like above) ?

for example, in PHP you can copy function, like :

```
$my = MyLongFunctionName(arg1, arg2....);
//execute
$my(arg1, arg2....)
```

## P.S. Note to all downvoters and duplicate-markers:

this topic is not duplicate, because that referred topic doesnt answer the question at all. It executes plain function, and even says, that it is not alias at all:
[image]

so, that topic doesnt solve the problem. instead, I want to mirror(a.k.a. ALIAS) whole overloads of specific method with i.e. `my()`,  which can accept variation of parameters. so, please stop mindless downvotings of what you dont read.

Comment: I think the answer to this question is as close as you're going to get: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088567/creating-an-alias-for-a-function-name-in-c-sharp (other than Ctrl+R, Ctrl+R in VS)

Comment: why my topic is marked as duplicate, while that referred topic doesnt answer the question at all. It executes plain function, and I want to mirror whole overloads of methods with i.e. `my()` which can accept variation of prameters. so, all downvoters and moderator, made a mistake.

Comment: The answer is "no". You can't do that. It's not possible.

Comment: @EdPlunkett thank you, yes i wanted an answer, and that's all (but why it was closed i dont understand).

Comment: "The closest possible approximation" is considered "an answer" by a lot of folks. Also, many no doubt consider the question silly -- it's a form of code obfuscation (like operator overloading, anybody who'll use it will abuse it), modern text editors and monitors offer cast real estate, and (since this is C#) Intellisense remembers the names for you. That's all IMO maybe but I suspect others see it the same way. FTR I didn't dv.

Comment: Those objections can apply to extension methods as well; I have no doubt somebody out there is busily engaged in unspeakable abuse of that feature. But extension methods also make LINQ possible.

Comment: @EdPlunkett thanks, my topic was re-opened. you can make an answer, i'll upvote you.

Comment: @EdPlunkett , so you say, the only way to make a call to long function name with my shorter-func name, is to make an overload of functions like original?

Comment: I recommend, urge, implore, advocate, suggest, counsel, exhort, enjoin, and entreat you to use the "long" method names as they are. Why are you obfuscating your code? You just don't like long names? Bad idea.

Comment: Another bad idea, by the way is arguing with the *presumed* motives of downvoters. All that'll get you is more downvotes, not least because there's a good chance around here that at least some of them understand your question better than you do. .

Comment: @EdPlunkett thanks for responses, I really appreciate.  but i am not going to quarreller with you, it doesnt matter why i want, you are arguing with your statement i think .  `..another bad idea is arguing with the presumed motives...`

Comment: Well, we'll have to agree to disagree about whether I'm arguing with myself or with somebody else. Or I'll have to agree to disagree with myself about that.

Comment: @EdPlunkett ed, i asked how to achieve that. so, i had some motives. you say that its a bad idea to argue with one's presumed motives. so, i wanted to acheive something. if someone had answer, should better to posted that. like someone did (whether "possible" or "not possible" answer, with addition if it's recommended or not). thnx really ed, i value your time you answered  me, i think it will help me somehow.

Comment: Fair enough. But on Stack Overflow, arguing with the presumed motives of downvoters is a trigger for further downvoting. My presumptions about your motives won't get me downvoted, but they must have gotten on your nerves, and I apologize. Now that you mention it, why *do* you want to do this?

Comment: not nerves, but on my time. most questions I ask, are the one that are not "default recommened way" (which i can find out easily). so, when i ask soemthing, that means i dont want a recommended way, instead want to achieve something trick. then getting response why i dont do it with recommended way. so, actually it is on my time, but if someone was me, probably will be on nerves too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid what you are asking is not possible.

What you want is a kind of delegate for a whole bunch of methods. It's called a `method group`.

> A method group is a set of overloaded methods resulting from a member lookup (§7.4).

For example `something.ToString` is a method group. It may contain one or more methods, depending on whether `ToString` has overloads for this specific class.

This is a compile time construct. You cannot put a method group into a variable, like you can with a single function. You can make a delegate from a method group, but that involves getting a specific overload and transforming only that into the delegate.

Comment: Thanks for understanding what i wanted! is something like this possible (phseudo-code):  `foreach( original_method  m in origiinal_methods ) {     set my_new_method as original_method ; }`

Comment: @T.TTodua Further to nvoigt's remarks, consider a reference that refers to *some largely arbitrary method group of some arbitrary class* -- both known only at runtime. Now you're doing overload resolution at runtime, which is expensive. And for what do we introduce this hidden trap into the language? A small number of programmers want to save some keystrokes without using Intellisense? Or what? You'll never sell the compiler team on that idea.

Comment: @T.Todua Using Reflection, you could do whatever you wanted. Get all methods of your choice (probably with the name X) into an array then do something with them. But that's a lot of code and will be way worse than using the original long name.

Comment: nvoigt thanks, i think you may be right.

@EdPlunkett you could post all comments as one answer, i think, it's worth.